# How to handle redeeming a consumable Promo Code for the App Store

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store

I have searched everywhere for this but haven't found the answer to my problem. This is the scenario:

I have a game live in the App Store. I have consumable IAPs for x number of Coins. I generated a Promo Code for a user to have some free Coins. He redeemed the code successfully in the App Store, but when he opened my game his Coins weren't credited. He tried tapping the 'Restore' button, restarting his device, and logging out and then back in again with his Apple ID, but nothing worked.

I tried it myself with another consumable Promo Code and couldn't get it to work either. I successfully redeemed a non-consumable IAP however.

So my question is, do I have to handle a consumable Promo Code being used in my code? Otherwise, how can users redeem  consumable Promo Codes?

*Edit: showing my code*

GameStoreViewController.swift (to select an IAP to buy from a table view)

```
@objc func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath!) {
        // First, make sure the user is authorised to make payments on his/her device
        if IAPHelper.canMakePayments() {
            // Then, make sure the product has been retrieved and placed in the _coinProducts array. If not, show alert
            if _coinProducts.count > 0 {
                activitySpinnerStart()
                print("row \((indexPath as NSIndexPath).row) tapped")
                let product = _coinProducts[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
                IAPList.store.buyProduct(product)  // Purchasing the product. Fires productPurchased(notification:)

            } else {
                showAlertWith(Localization("NoConnectionAlertTitle"), message: Localization("NoConnectionAlertMessage"))
            }

        } else {
            showAlertWith(Localization("NoConnectionAlertTitle"), message: Localization("NoIAPAllowedMessage"))
        }
}
```

IAPHelper.swift:

```
import StoreKit

/// Notification that is generated when a product is purchased.
public let IAPHelperPurchaseNotification = "IAPHelperPurchaseNotification"

/// Notification that is generated when a transaction fails.
public let IAPHelperTransactionFailedNotification = "IAPHelperTransactionFailedNotification"

/// Notification that is generated when cannot retrieve IAPs from iTunes.
public let IAPHelperConnectionErrorNotification = "IAPHelperConnectionErrorNotification"

/// Notification that is generated when we need to stop the spinner.
public let IAPHelperStopSpinnerNotification = "IAPHelperStopSpinnerNotification"



/// Product identifiers are unique strings registered on the app store.
public typealias ProductIdentifier = String

/// Completion handler called when products are fetched.
public typealias ProductsRequestCompletionHandler = (_ success: Bool, _ products: [SKProduct]?) -> ()


/// A Helper class for In-App-Purchases.
open class IAPHelper : NSObject  {

/// MARK: - User facing API

fileprivate let productIdentifiers: Set<ProductIdentifier>
fileprivate var purchasedProductIdentifiers = Set<ProductIdentifier>()

fileprivate var productsRequest: SKProductsRequest?
fileprivate var productsRequestCompletionHandler: ProductsRequestCompletionHandler?

// These two notifications are private, so are needed in addition to the public ones on line 12
//static let IAPHelperPurchaseNotification = "IAPHelperPurchaseNotification"
//static let IAPHelperTransactionFailedNotification = "IAPHelperTransactionFailedNotification"

/// Initialize the helper.  Pass in the set of ProductIdentifiers supported by the app.
public init(productIds: Set<ProductIdentifier>) {
    self.productIdentifiers = productIds

    for productIdentifier in productIds {
        let purchased = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: productIdentifier)
        if purchased {
            purchasedProductIdentifiers.insert(productIdentifier)
            print("Previously purchased: \(productIdentifier)")
        } else {
            print("Not purchased: \(productIdentifier)")
        }
    }

    super.init()

    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
}
}

// MARK: - StoreKit API

extension IAPHelper {

public func requestProducts(_ completionHandler: @escaping ProductsRequestCompletionHandler) {
    productsRequest?.cancel()
    productsRequestCompletionHandler = completionHandler

    productsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productIdentifiers)
    productsRequest!.delegate = self
    productsRequest!.start()
}

public func buyProduct(_ product: SKProduct) {
    print("Buying \(product.productIdentifier)...")
    let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)
}

public func isProductPurchased(_ productIdentifier: ProductIdentifier) -> Bool {
    return purchasedProductIdentifiers.contains(productIdentifier)
}

public class func canMakePayments() -> Bool {
    return SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()
}

public func restorePurchases() {
    SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()
}

// Adding functions from SA
public func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue) {
    print("Restore queue finished.")
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: IAPHelperStopSpinnerNotification), object: nil)
}

public func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError error: Error) {
    print("Restore queue failed.")
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: IAPHelperConnectionErrorNotification), object: nil)
}

}

// MARK: - SKProductsRequestDelegate

extension IAPHelper: SKProductsRequestDelegate {
public func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
    print("Loaded list of products...")
    let products = response.products
    productsRequestCompletionHandler?(true, products)
    clearRequestAndHandler()

    for p in products {
        print("Found product: \(p.productIdentifier) \(p.localizedTitle) \(p.price.floatValue)")
    }
}

public func request(_ request: SKRequest, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    print("Failed to load list of products.")
    print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    productsRequestCompletionHandler?(false, nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: IAPHelperConnectionErrorNotification), object: nil)
    clearRequestAndHandler()
}

fileprivate func clearRequestAndHandler() {
    productsRequest = nil
    productsRequestCompletionHandler = nil
}
}

// MARK: - SKPaymentTransactionObserver

extension IAPHelper: SKPaymentTransactionObserver {

public func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
    for transaction in transactions {
        switch (transaction.transactionState) {
        case .purchased:
            completeTransaction(transaction)
            break
        case .failed:
            failedTransaction(transaction)
            break
        case .restored:
            restoreTransaction(transaction)
            break
        case .deferred:
            break
        case .purchasing:
            break
        }
    }
}

fileprivate func completeTransaction(_ transaction: SKPaymentTransaction) {
    print("completeTransaction...")
    deliverPurchaseNotificationForIdentifier(transaction.payment.productIdentifier)
    SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
}

fileprivate func restoreTransaction(_ transaction: SKPaymentTransaction) {
    guard let productIdentifier = transaction.original?.payment.productIdentifier else { return }

    print("restoreTransaction... \(productIdentifier)")
    deliverPurchaseNotificationForIdentifier(productIdentifier)
    SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
}

fileprivate func failedTransaction(_ transaction: SKPaymentTransaction) {
    print("failedTransaction...")
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: IAPHelperStopSpinnerNotification), object: nil)
    if transaction.error!._code != SKError.paymentCancelled.rawValue {
        print("Transaction Error: \(String(describing: transaction.error?.localizedDescription))")
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: IAPHelperTransactionFailedNotification), object: nil)
    } else {
        print("Transaction Error else statement")
    }

    SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: IAPHelperTransactionFailedNotification), object: nil)

}

fileprivate func deliverPurchaseNotificationForIdentifier(_ identifier: String?) {
    guard let identifier = identifier else { return }

    purchasedProductIdentifiers.insert(identifier)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: identifier)
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: IAPHelperPurchaseNotification), object: identifier)
}
}
```

IAPList.swift:

```
import Foundation

// Use enum as a simple namespace.  (It has no cases so you can't instantiate it.)
public struct IAPList {

  /// TODO:  Change this to whatever you set on iTunes connect
  fileprivate static let Prefix = "com.xxx.xxx."

  /// MARK: - Supported Product Identifiers
  /// List your IAPs here:
  public static let PackOf4000Coins =   Prefix + "4000Coins"   
  public static let PackOf10000Coins =  Prefix + "10000Coins"
  public static let PackOf30000Coins =  Prefix + "30000Coins"
  public static let PackOf75000Coins =  Prefix + "75000Coins"
  public static let PackOf175000Coins = Prefix + "175000Coins"
  public static let RemoveAds =  Prefix + "RemoveAds"
  public static let PlayerEditor =  Prefix + "PlayerEditor"

  // All of the products assembled into a set of product identifiers.
  fileprivate static let productIdentifiers: Set<ProductIdentifier> = 
  [IAPList.PackOf4000Coins, IAPList.PackOf10000Coins, IAPList.PackOf30000Coins, 
IAPList.PackOf75000Coins, PackOf175000Coins, RemoveAds, PlayerEditor]

  /// Static instance of IAPHelper.
  public static let store = IAPHelper(productIds: IAPList.productIdentifiers)
}

  /// Return the resource name for the product identifier.
  func resourceNameForProductIdentifier(_ productIdentifier: String) -> String? {
      return productIdentifier.components(separatedBy: ".").last
}
```

Comment: Do you create your payment transaction observer as soon as your app launches?

Comment: @Paulw11 No, it is in a file called IAPHelper.swift, not the AppDelegate file. Is that an issue?

Comment: As long as you instantiate that helper pretty early. If you only create an instance when the user goes to buy something then you won’t get the pending transactions. It is odd that the non-consumable promo IAP was delivered, or did that work because of restoration?

Comment: @Paulw11 I think you are correct, I seem to create an instance only when the 'buy' button is tapped. I am using source code from a Ray Wenderlich tutorial, so I'm not 100% sure. I have edited my question above to show my code - how should I create a payment transaction observer earlier? And yes, the non-consumable worked because of restoration. Thanks for your help by the way!

Comment: If you have IAPs then one of the first things you should do when your app starts is instantiate an object to be the payment queue observer. I typically do this in `didFinishLaunching` and have the app delegate hold a reference to it (or you can create it as a singleton). This is important because any transactions that you didn't complete before your app was terminated will be presented to this queue observer when the app starts.  Before promo codes this was a pretty rare situation; typically the purchase is completed without the app being terminated.

Comment: With promo codes the purchase happens outside your app and so when the app is launched you need a transaction queue observer to find out about that purchase. Or, your app may be running but suspended when the code is redeemed through the App Store. When your app returns to the foreground the transaction will be delivered to your queue observer; if you don't have one then you won't find out about the code redemption.

Comment: @Paulw11 Ah ok, that makes sense - thanks for the info. So is it simply a case of instantiating this object with something like: let iapHelper = IAPHelper(). Do I leave everything else as it is?

Comment: Yes; I haven't gone through your code in detail by but it looks ok.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks very much. :-) If you'd like to put some kind of answer I'd be happy to accept it as correct.

Comment: @Paulw11 I am having trouble implementing this and have posted a new question about it - I'd be grateful if you could take a look! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51897838/best-practice-to-add-a-transaction-queue-observer-at-application-launch-for-stor

Comment: @Paulw11 Don't worry, I figured it out :-)

Comment: I am having an issue with redeeming. They just arent appearing on my payments queue at all. Do you know what your final solution was? I am my Iap functionality from the AppDelegate

Comment: @paul_f my final solution was to use SwiftyStoreKit as it was much simpler - see this answer I gave in another thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52853827/3679629